# in a delta table, how can i find the number of files per partition?

Tags: python, pandas

in a delta table, how can i find the number of files per partition? also looking to find the size of each file as well. i've tried this code, but I run into an error TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable:

```
from delta.tables import *
JDeltaLog = spark._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog
delta_log = JDeltaLog.forTable(spark, path)
all_files_jdf = delta_log.snapshot().allFiles().toDF()
all_files_df = DataFrame(all_files_jdf, spark._wrapped)
partition_counts_df = (
    all_files_df
    .groupBy([f.col('partitionValues')[key].alias(key) for key in partition_cols])
    .count()
)
```

Comment: Which line gets that message?  Is this Python code?  And where does JDeltaLog come from?  There are no Google hits for that name.

Comment: sorry i edited my initial post. it is failing on line 3 where delta_log =, and yes this is python